# How to add support for Jenkinsfile* in PhpStorm?

Tags: autocomplete, jenkins-pipeline, phpstorm, settings

In PhpStorm the `Jenkinsfile`'s code is highlighted and autocompleted. In my project I have multiple `Jenkinsfile`s (like `Jenkinsfile_DEV`, `Jenkinsfile_TEST`, `Jenkinsfile_PROD`). In that files highlighting and autocompletion are not working.

**How to get PhpStorm supporting not only the files with the name `Jenkinsfile`, but also associate other files with this highlighting/autocompletion (e.g. `Jenkinsfile_*`)?**

What I tried so far: I looked for the "Jenkinsfile" entry in the `File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Recognized file types`. The plan was just to add an entry like "Jenkinsfile*" to the "Jenkinsfile" entry. But I haven't found an entry like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkinsfile syntax is provided by Groovy textmate bundles at File | Settings | Editor | TextMate Bundles. Unfortunately it's not configurable: Jenkinsfile is hardcoded to be associated with Groovy in PhpStorm. The only option here is to add `.groovy` extension to those files.